# How can I stop a timer on WP7 from an external event?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need a timer that redirects me to another page after 5 seconds, the problem is that it redirects me to this page every 5 seconds, so I need to stop it. If I stop It after `tmr.Start()` It doesn't execute the event. How can I do this in the event `OnTimerTick`?

```
DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
tmr.Start();

void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lvlSet1/s1lvl3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));            
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Description

Two possible solutions.

1. Create your `DispatcherTimer` instance on class level, not in your method. Then you can acces them from your `OnTimerTick` Method.
2. You can cast the sender to `DispatcherTimer` in your `OnTimerTick` method.

### Sample

**1. Solution**

```
    public class YourClass
    {
        DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();

        public void YourMethodThatStartsTheTimer()
        {
            tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lvlSet1/s1lvl3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }      
    }
```

**2. Solution**

```
    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lvlSet1/s1lvl3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

### More Information

[MSDN: DispatcherTimer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Trying structuring your code like this. Is is going to keep your timer object in scope so you can stop it after the first tick happens.

```
class SimpleExample
{
    DispatcherTimer timer;

    public SimpleExample()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/lvlSet1/s1lvl3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));            
    }
}
```